# Using redux connect function loses class information in my IDE (PhpStorm/WebStorm)

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, phpstorm, webstorm

Using the connect function from redux seems to make my IDE (PhpStorm) lose the ability to "Find Usages" on my classes. I assume because `connect` returns `any`, so `import SomeClass from SomeClass.ts` loses the type information from that file.

`export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SomeClass);`

From the redux docs:

> It does not modify the component class passed to it; instead, it returns a new, connected component class for you to use.

But I want my IDE to treat this as if it was my original class/component so it has all the type information.

One way I found how to fix this is by using annotations with `@connect`, but this requires me to put `mapStateToProps` & `mapDispatchToProps` functions above the class. I prefer to keep my class files fairly clean with the class at the very top of the file.

This gives `Block-scoped variable 'mapSateToProps' used before its declaration`
    import { connect } from 'react-redux'

```
@connect(mapStateToProps)
class TestClass {

}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {

}
```

Is there a way for me to use connect, keep the class type information in my IDE, and have `mapStateToProps` either below the class or inside the class as static functions? Or just anywhere else in the same file?

I'm using TypeScript & Babel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write `mapStateToProps` as a function instead, since when using the `function` keyword the declaration is [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting)

e.g.

```
function mapStateToProps(state: TypeOfYourRootStore, props: TypeOfYourComponentsProps) {}
```

Comment: Oh yup, that does it. Thank you! I guess I didn't think of this because `mapDispatchToProps` was an object, but it looks like I can use the function version of it instead.